# calling validation on tab click ( jQuery-Validation-Engine )

Tags: jquery-validation-engine

I have set up the  jQuery-Validation-Engine addon (https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) and it works great on the submit button.

However, since i invoked a tab-based interface, it doesn't really bring the user back to the proper tab with the error fields.

As a work around, i've decided its better to validate each tab when leaving to the next one (as it is a step-wise tab) so that the button click at the end will only 'really' need to correct any errors on the currently displayed tab.

I'm using a simple  anchor to call some div swaps (using negative margins for content off-page).
I'd like to invoke the validation method to this as well.

Documentation says it can only be attached to a form element.

Any ideas?

Update- i ditched the tab idea and am now using one big form so this no longer really applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No support led to going after a different approach.  No longer needed.